# radio button, set first item as selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

i have a page built in asp.net c#. it holds a list of radio buttons on the left side and when a user selects one of the buttons, a content window on the right displays data associated to the button. i would like to set the "selectedindex=0" so on page load the user sees the content of the first radio button.

In my code behind, if i set radioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 0 within the radio list databind method, the user will see the first radio selection on page load. But the content associated with pre selected radio button does not display. What do i need to include in my content viewer's databinding method do make this happen. Thanks!

-------- code behind

```
public partial class test_123 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void SqlDataSource2_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {

      radioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 0


    }
    protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried radioButtonList1.DataBind()?

Comment: did not work but thanks for your input.

Comment: I would go with client side solution if the wall becomes too high to climb. If it comes to this let me know and I'll come with some sample code.

Comment: actually, within the page load method i placed the following code to get it working. does this seem like a good approach. `if(Page.IsPostBack) return; RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 0; RadioButtonList1.DataBind();`

Comment: umm.. isn't that what I suggested before and you said "did not work"?? bit confused now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged() explicitly after you set the SelectedIndex to 0 on page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
        return;

    radioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
}

protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadContent(ListBox1.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: `loadconent(Listbox1.selectedIndex);` isn't recognized. did you mean to write something else. thanks for your input!

Comment: Yes, it supposed to be your logic to load content based on selectedindex.

Comment: i used part of your code to get my solution so thanks! i really appreciate it! you helped get me on the right track.